# Printing the contents of a list of key value tuples using mapM function in IO (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in a main=do block:

```
let finalList = mergeKey x
```

`mergeKey` takes a list of key value pairs like `[("Hi",1),("Hello",2),("Hello",3)]` and adds up all the values that have the same key parameter. So `finalList` would be `[("Hi",1),("Hello",5)]`
I want to output this list to the terminal so I know my function mergeKey is working as it should be. However, I'm getting confused as to how I can use `print` to do this. I know I will have to use mapM since finalList is a list, so I tried this:

`mapM print finalList`
However, it gives me an unexpected type error. Am I using the print and mapM functions wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are able to print lists directly, so `print finalList` should work. The type error that you are probably getting is that `mapM` returns an `IO [a]`, while `main` is supposed to return an `IO ()`. Try using the function `mapM_` instead.

Comment: `main`'s signature doesn't have to be `IO ()`: any `IO a` is legal. But I agree it seems likely that in this case it's specifically annotated `IO ()`. It would be nice if the question included the actual error message, instead of "a type error", so we could be sure.